# Rails 3, on some computers get Errno::ENOMEM: Not enough space, when I do Model.all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, space

I have Rails 3, with webrick, running a sqlite3 database.  On my standard linux desktop, doing Word.all (Word is my model), I have no problems, even though there are 10,000 entries in my database. I have scopes to display them 2000 at a time, to make things more tractable.

On my Windows 7 laptop, it's a very different story. I can only get about 400 Words at a time, or I get that "Not enough space" error.

I can open up window's task manager, and the memory barely even blips.  On the console, the command returns almost instantly (it clearly has not done anything to several hundred entries before giving up).

What is going on here? My laptop isn't exactly much worse than my desktop, so I don't think i"m actually hitting any RAM limits... Is there some weird Ruby thing going on?

EDIT: It's not just a server issue either, i see the same thing in the rails console, as well... So, webrick might not be an issue...

If it were code, you'd think I"d see it across platforms, not just on my laptop... Even then, how can it be my code if all I'm typing is Word.all (no custom code) and the database is clearly set up right (I don't have issues getting any individual entry, just not too many at a time)

-jenny

Comment: 1.9.2 on the desktop, and possibly 1.9.2 (but maybe 1.8.7, I'll have to check later) on the laptop

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 0):

webrick is a very simple web application server think to work only for development.
I have no experience of it on windows os , but,anyway, i have many probel with it when test limit situation. you could try the [mongrel](https://github.com/mattetti/mongrel) gem , if the problem persist it's something in your code.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to clarify that this is happening in the console as well, so webrick is probably actually not the issue